# Specifying what row to start onEdit Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-sheets

I want this onEdit script on google Spreadsheet to start with Row 2, which skips my header row, but I cannot get it to work with my existing code? 
Can someone out there help a noob out?

```
function onEdit(e)
{
  var ss = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var rr  = e.source.getActiveRange();


//comment 2 lines below if you want it working on all sheets, not just on 2nd one
  if(ss.getIndex()!= 1)
    if(ss.getIndex()!= 2) 
      if(ss.getIndex()!= 3) 
  return;
 ///

  var firstRow = rr.getRow();
  var lastRow = rr.getLastRow();

//the last modified date will appear in the 43th column which is the Last Update Column
  for(var r=firstRow; r<=lastRow; r++)
    ss.getRange(r, 43).setValue(new Date());
}
```

Comment: Hello, 

Looks like you are on the right track. I wrote a similar program for a google spreadsheet where I want to ignore the header. What error do you run into with your code? 

-jk

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. This code does what I want EXCEPT that it updates the header row, which is a frozen row. I have tried several different ways to skip the header row by using .offset and other code examples I found butI do not understand the scripting code well enough to get it working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Spreadsheet SCRIPT Check if edited cell is in a specific range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583187/google-spreadsheet-script-check-if-edited-cell-is-in-a-specific-range)

Answer (score 1):

Just check if the current row is within the header, and exit the trigger:

```
function onEdit(e)
{
  var rr = e.range;
  var ss = e.range.getSheet();

  var headerRows = 1;  // # header rows to ignore

  if (rr.getRow() <= headerRows) return;
  ...
```