# Add a timestamp for each answer of a Google Form in their adjacent cell in the spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, timestamp, google-sheets, google-forms

I've seen various related answers to my question but none that actually answers it. I've tried different things so I hope anyone is able to help!

I have a Google Form with multiple pages that each contain one question. In addition to the final time stamp that appears on the form (which is standard) I'd like to measure the time it took to answer each question. I've found some solutions that add the time stamp when a cell is filled out (such as [How to automatically add a timestamp in google spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26374359/how-to-automatically-add-a-timestamp-in-google-spreadsheet) and [Automatic timestamp when a cell is filled out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11458470/automatic-timestamp-when-a-cell-is-filled-out)) but I believe the answers from the form are not stored in the spreadsheet until all answers are provided.

So I was wondering if anyone knows if it is possible in a script to create a variable of the current time after each question in the form and subsequently show these in the spreadsheet once it is submitted?

Thanks.

Nadine

Comment: Not possible. Many past questions have asked about controlling Forms via script "on the fly", while a user is filling them out. That is not supported. You could get that functionality by creating an HTML form or form-chain.

Comment: I think this answer can assist: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35996268/1726419

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Google Forms allow for 'On-the-Fly' Section Duplication?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36465387/does-google-forms-allow-for-on-the-fly-section-duplication)

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, but you would have to use multiple forms.

Google forms are static and can't be edited or altered with script during a session (user opening a form until they submit it). You can't pull out values that a user has entered into a form until they have submitted it.

As a result you could have an initial form which collects all the values which would influence subsequent forms, then use a script to take the results and create a new form, (e.g. with 12 fields for the 12 provisioned users in your initial example) and then email a link to this form to your end user.