# Measure time to fill section - google forms

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms, timespan

I'm trying to use google forms for a research questionnaire.
for some of the sections I want to automatically measure the time takes the user to fill.

there is no option like this in google forms.
I've tried to copy the form source, and fill the time with javascript but it didn't worked (Cross-Origin issue) - Didn't succeed to host the copied form.

How it can be done - how can I measure the time that took to answer a form?
is there an other forms-like service that allow measuring time per question?

Comment: You can create your own custom input form with an Apps Script stand alone web app.  And then use a timer:  [documentation about timer](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)  Stack Overflow is not for general advice.  You can join the Apps Script group.  [Link to Apps Script Group](https://plus.google.com/communities/102471985047225101769)

Comment: @SandyGood - thanks for your comment, I would be very thankful if you can answer with an example of this issue - example of using App Script to measure time. I'm not looking for general advice, I just want to be able to get the time measured as another input

Comment: To get a finished product, you'll need to create a stand alone web app.  Here is a link to an Apps Script file that you can make a copy of.  [Link to Apps Script file](https://script.google.com/d/1QHMW6N47xHTd25WXZVUh3ipRr9FQYgl8HyX5lXYZn2K-19sIkgVKxWzi/edit?usp=sharing)  It's an example of an Apps Script Web App that is an input form, made to look like a Google Form.   So, the first thing you need to do, is create the stand alone web app, and understand how that all fits together.  Then we can talk about the timer.

Comment: @SandyGood created an app that uses FormApp object. how can I add the timer to it?

Comment: Ok, the form app is not a good solution, I guess the solution is full app - no shortcuts avilable...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Google Forms allow for 'On-the-Fly' Section Duplication?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36465387/does-google-forms-allow-for-on-the-fly-section-duplication)

Comment: @Rubén, It is not a duplicate at all. this question is regarded to time measurment and it have been asked a month before your recomanded question. those two problems may have similar solution but they are not dumlicates. please remove your comment

Comment: It's a duplicate because the answer/solution is the same. The other question answer has more votes than the answer to this question and it was accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, It's can be done with google app scripts
source example: [here](https://script.google.com/d/1JaHQbhaFQeRLpYMZJGP-Iz6pJd_AeoN4vHvbZZgZKn2YMc8kkm0zHuKq/edit?usp=sharing)

Not as good as "out of the box" but hey - IT WORKS!

Comment: To clarify for others - **Google Forms can't track time**. This route takes you completely out of Google Forms and into Apps Script. There's a lot of ways you can write the JS to track, store and even display the time back to the user. This sample was just 1 way within a custom web app.

Comment: The video isn't available anymore.

Comment: @Rubén  You need to implement the form yourself in HTML... as a google apps script.