# Does Google Forms allow for 'On-the-Fly' Section Duplication?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

This is such an open ended question, (and Google search returned mixed results) but basically, I am trying to create a Google Form that dynamically creates new Sections based on a 'key' value the Form user would input in the beginning.

> E.g. "How many users are you provisioning for?"

The input value (string) would be converted into a number (float) value and would then determine how many subsequent Section Types are created.

Is this even possible with Google's existing Google Forms/Google Script framework?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible, but you would have to use multiple forms.

Google forms are static and can't be edited or altered with script during a session (user opening a form until they submit it).
You can't pull out values that a user has entered into a form until they have submitted it.

As a result you could have an initial form which collects all the values which would influence subsequent forms, then use a script to take the results and create a new form, (e.g. with 12 fields for the 12 provisioned users in your initial example) and then email a link to this form to your end user.