# Auto enter data (current time) into a google form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to use a Google form to capture time blocks throughout the day.

When clicking on the link to bring up a new form, I want to **populate the current time into the START TIME question.**

[screenshot of the question in the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U65lc.png)

Then when the form is submitted (after some minutes or hours), the STOP TIME will be the timestamp that is recorded in the responses sheet - which will let me easily calculate the duration.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Have you ever built a form in Google Apps Script?

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this answer it is not possible to track the time taken to fill a Google form unless you deploy it as a web app.

The issue is with the form `onOpen` trigger that only works when an editor opens the form to modify it (therefore it will not work for respondents). However, you can actually get the time of the form's submission using an `onSubmit` trigger *(in your script go to **Edit -> Current Project's triggers**)* and create an [onSubmit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_forms_events) linked to the following function in your code:

```js
function onSubmit(){
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var currentTime = new Date();
  form.setConfirmationMessage(Utilities.formatDate(currentTime, 'GMT', 'MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss'));  
}
```

Note: I have used the method [formatDate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format) of Apps Script.

Nevertheless, this will only get you the time of the form submission. As I mentioned earlier, you can get the time taken to fill a form if you deploy it as a web app. For more information about how to achieve this [check this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35996268).

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)