# Add a timestamp programmatically

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a code to Google Spreadsheets . In VBA code it is very simple. My goal is, when a particular cell is filled , another cell displays the date and time of completion .

In VBA:

```
Function DateTime()
  DateTime = NOW
End Function
```

Comment: Which cell are you monitoring and which one do you want the date in? "new Date()" would give the present date/time in JS.

Comment: Did not work only replacing new Date() for Now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [To add data in one cell automatically when another cell is edited in google spreadsheets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865134/to-add-data-in-one-cell-automatically-when-another-cell-is-edited-in-google-spre)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your most recent comment stating that you want to call a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) from the Google Sheet frontend, all you will need in your **Script Editor** (backend) is:

```
function timeStamp() {
  return new Date();
}
```

You can then call that function from a formula in your Sheet, very similar to what you wrote already:

```
=IF( ISBLANK(A1), "", timeStamp() )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that will help you out of what you are trying to achieve.

Code below will add the date in the very next column of whichever field you will input a value into.

```
//onEdit is the default "on edit event handler" provided by google app script
function onEdit(e){
  var spreadSheet = e.source;
  var sheet = spreadSheet.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;
  //only add the date in the next column if value in cell is not empty
  if(range.getValue() != ""){
    var col = range.getColumn();
    var row = range.getRow();
    //get the very next column
    var newRange = sheet.getRange(row, col + 1);
    newRange.setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

Hope this will help.

**NB:** *Please note this code will work with [scripts bound to google apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) only.*

Comment: Hello , apparently did not work. I believe that my need is more simple. I need to put together a formula IF(IFSBLANK(A1);" ";myFunction ( ) ) .
In other words , I need myFunction given the fixed date and time so that A1 is met . Its formula has not done this and not become scalable - the tests I did. Example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i05H3zcI51v4UkFrHpBnTUfJ__1pp46um99wn_VpgC8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @GabrielPiffer: Relevante information regarding the question should be included on the question.